# HTML file issue 'è' being turned into a strange character

Tags: html

I'm getting started with html,however the following script doesn't do what it's supposed to:

```
<h1>Ciao Mondo!</h1>
<p>Questa è la nostra prima pagina HTML!</p>
```

The result produced in my browser changes the `è` to `Ã¨` :

> Ciao Mondo!
>
> Questa Ã¨ la nostra prima pagina HTML!

Comment: There might be other reasons to close this, but I think it has to be allowed to use foreign language in questions about language encodings.

Comment: @visibleman totally, clearly, indubitably agree with you.

Comment: @Rob The suggestion to close this is ridiculous. The question is in English, the other language identifies the encoding issue, the `'è'` to `Ã`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert this tag inside the `head` section of your html and see what happens:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

With this you are instructing the browser how to deal with the special characters of Italian language.

Ciao Antonio!

Comment: Stuppendo! Please, check my answer as the correct one. Arrivederci.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 way, using the meta charset attribute. The lang attribute does not affect encoding, it is just there to aid screen-readers and search engines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<h1>Ciao Mondo!</h1>
<p>Questa è la nostra prima pagina HTML!</p>
</html>
```